# How do I fix this child class' initializer list error?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, initializer-list

Parent class is Vehicle, child class is Car. Have to use initializer list for all constructors which is proving to be a challenge for me. I keep getting the following error for what I have currently:

```
car.cpp:7:1: error: redefinition of 'Car::Car()'
Car::Car()
^
In file included from car.cpp:3:0:
car.h:12:5: note: 'Car::Car()' previously defined here
     Car() : Vehicle("NoID", -1, "NoMake", "NoModel", "NoColor") {}
     ^
```

As a novice I am mildly familiar with basic initialization lists but not when it comes to using them in child classes. In case it wasn't glaringly obvious this is for an assignment; I am just looking for help diagnosing the above error, not a full solution.

**vehicle.h**

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle
{
protected:
    /* Each of these data item represent something any type of vehicle
    will have, so it makes sense these would be in the base class. */

    // added a parent constructor so child classes can use
    // these variables in initializer list
    Vehicle(string id, int year, string make, string model,
            string color) : id(id), year(year), make(make),
                            model(model), color(color) {}
    string id;
    int year;
    string make;
    string model;
    string color;

public:
    Vehicle();
    // Vehicle(string id, int year, string make, string model, string color);
    Vehicle(ifstream &infile);
    // virtual ~Vehicle();
    string getID();
    void setID(string ID);
    virtual void printInfo(ofstream &out);
};

#endif
```

**car.h**

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "vehicle.h"
using namespace std;

class Car : public Vehicle
{
private:
    Car() : Vehicle("NoID", -1, "NoMake", "NoModel", "NoColor") {}
    int doors;
    string paymentType;

public:
    // Car();
    Car(string id, int year, string make, string model, string color, int doors, 
string paymentType);
    Car(ifstream &infile);

    int getDoors();
    void setDoors(int numdoors);

    string getPaymentType();
    void setPaymentType(string pt);

    void printInfo(ofstream &out);
};

#endif
```

**car.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "car.h"
#include "vehicle.h"
using namespace std;

Car::Car()
{
    // default constructor initialization list?
}

Car::Car(string id, int year, string make, string model,
         string color, int doors, string paymentType)
{
    // parameterized constructor
}

Car::Car(ifstream &infile)
{
    // regular constructor i think
}

int Car::getDoors()
{
    return doors;
}

void Car::setDoors(int numdoors)
{
    doors = numdoors;
}

string Car::getPaymentType()
{
    return paymentType;
}

void Car::setPaymentType(string pt)
{
    paymentType = pt;
}

void Car::printInfo(ofstream &out)
{
// unfinished
}
```

Comment: A good technique to help find and solve problems like this is to back up the code and then start removing stuff (carefully so you don't add new errors) until the error goes away. The problem is in what you last removed. If that doesn't set off a light bulb over your head and let you fix the problem yourself, you're in a much better position to ask a question because the code will usually be a LOT smaller. Consult [mre] for further inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared **and defined** your constructor here

```
Car() : Vehicle("NoID", -1, "NoMake", "NoModel", "NoColor") {}
```

therefore, the definition in the cpp file is a second definition, which is illegal

```
Car::Car()
{
    // default constructor initialization list?
}
```

If you'd like to move the implementation to the cpp file, then change the header to just have the declaration

```
// car.h
class Car : public Vehicle
{
    Car();
    ...
};

// car.cpp
Car::Car()
: Vehicle("NoID", -1, "NoMake", "NoModel", "NoColor")
{
    // default constructor initialization list?
}
```